# HttpWebRequest The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am trying to make web request to a website that does not require any credentials.

> I used postman utility with the cookie and it works fine. I took cookie from chrome browser.

. However, I tried setting cookie, TLS, use default credentials, but nothing is helping.

Main website: https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain On this website I go to developer tools and copy the cookie value.

Web Request URL: https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=APOLLOHOSP
Code:

```
     void DOSomething()
        {
            try
            {

                string html = string.Empty;
                string url = @"https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=APOLLOHOSP";

                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };


                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

                string cook = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(txtCookie.Text.Trim());
        
                Uri target = new Uri(url);
                request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;



                request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                request.PreAuthenticate = true;
                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                request.CookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie("cookie",cook) { Domain = "nseindia.com" });


                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

            

                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                Console.WriteLine(html);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Please help.

Comment: I write code for it and it works.
https://github.com/menshikovyaroslav/Authorizations/tree/master/Catalogs/www.nseindia.com

Comment: @YaroslavMenshikov Thanks for the help. However, Unable to run the code. It has missing dependencies. It would be great if you upload the complete solution. Particularly, its missing namespace for cookies object and also for CatalogSupportLibrary.Requests. Please upload entire solution. Thanks in advace!

Comment: CookieContainer - using System.Net;
CatalogSupportLibrary.Requests is in the same repository
https://github.com/menshikovyaroslav/Authorizations/tree/master/Support/CatalogSupportLibrary/Requests

Comment: @YaroslavMenshikov Thanks for reply. When I inspected Ajax request, I can see a very big cookie, but you managed to add 4 cookie values (bm_mi, ak_bmsc, bm_sv, nseappid, nsit). It would be great help if you let me know how you identified those as different cookies.

Comment: You can see all the cookies using Fiddler or in your browser.